# Why aren't my dwarfs doing archery training?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So I have been trying to follow [this](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=150494.0) guide (also on the [wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Advanced_Marksdwarf_Training_Guide)) to get my marksdorfs to do some archery training, but haven't had much luck. I uploaded my save [here](http://dffd.bay12games.com/file.php?id=12370) so you can see the issue.

My archery squad is called the Crystals of Pattrnng. On the equipment screen all of their positions uniforms have a green checkmark next to it, so I presume there are no equipment issues. I also checked and they all have bolts in their quivers. I set my training orders to train 1 minimum for every month, with 1 order for each soilder (5 total). I made 1 archery target for each squad member with ZTIQ enabled on each, with the direction being from top to bottom (which is correct in this case).

But for some reason even after waiting a long time they still aren't shooting. Instead they stick around saying soldering -(no orders), or they socialize. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Comment instead of an answer, because I haven't done this with the latest version yet, and it always seems to change somewhat. At some point, archers would only train if there was a target assigned to the squad, and they were OFF-Duty. 'Training' is melee training.  Also, some are a lot better about practicing than others. (Especially since the taverns came. They tend to absorb every dwarf they can.)